# Take photo during video-input

Tags: ios, face-detection, avcapturesession, avcapture

I'm currently trying to take an image in the best quality during capturing video at a lower quality. The problem is, that i'm using the video stream to check if face are in front of the cam and this needs lot's of resources, so i'm using a lower quality video stream and if there are any faces detected I want to take a photo in high quality.

Best regards and thank's for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can not have multiple capture sessions so at some point you will need to swap to higher resolution. First thing you are saying that face detection takes too much resources when using high res snapshots.. Why not try to simply down-sample the image and keep using high resolution all the time (send the down sampled one to the face detection, display the high res):

I would start with most common apple's graphic context and try to down scale it. If that takes too much cpu you could try to do the same on the GPU (find some library that does that or just create a simple program) or you could even try to simply drop odd lines and columns of the image as the raw data. In any of those cases you should also note that you probably do not need the face detection on the same thread as displaying, also you most likely don't even need a high frame rate for the detection (you display camera a full FPS but update the face recognition at 10 FPS for instance).

Another thing you can do is simply have the whole thing in low res, then when you need to take the image stop the session, start high res session, take a screenshot and swap back to low res for face detection.

Comment: Thank's for your answer. I've already tried your last method (the thing with the swapping), but the swapping was too slow for my purpose, but i think your first method would do the trick! I will try it and give you feedback here than!